# How to use filters with web3py to get event logs for a smart contract?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I'm looking to get event logs for a smart contract and I'm using Infura nodes for this. According to the documentation provided [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v4_migration.html#filters), I tried running

```
new_block_filter = web3.eth.filter('latest')
```

I think this should have been

```
new_block_filter = w3.eth.filter('latest')
```

where w3 should be something like

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/infura-project-id"))
```

but there's an error in the documentation. Anyways I tried this which I believe is the simplest way to create a filter as well the methods mentioned [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#module-web3.utils.filters).

Both of these result in an error that looks like

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 333, in filter
>       [filter_params],
>     File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 112, in request_blocking
>       raise ValueError(response["error"])
>
> ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_newFilter does not exist/is not available'}

Any ideas on how to create and use these filters and further how to get event logs for a smart contract when the topic parameter is known.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means what it says. Infura doesn't support the RPC method `eth_newFilter` over HTTPS, which is what your code ends up calling.

I believe the same code should work if you connect via WebSocket instead.

Comment: I am making use of Ropsten. I am not able to connect using websocket. When I try to create a Block filter, it hangs for infinite duration.